# Late 2013 MacBook Pro freezes after StartUp

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

Since yesterday, I can’t get past the login screen because my Mac freezes.

I‘ve tried starting in Recovery mode, and run disk repair but this didn’t solve the problem. Resetting the NVRAM didn’t work either. When starting in safe mode, the Mac freezes after approximately 3 minutes.

I have about 50 GB of free space on my Mac and am running macOS Sierra.

Comment: It just came to me mind: Maybe it’s the Mac that freezes, not the keyboard and mouse... It’s just that the consequence I see immediately is an unresponsive keyboard.

Comment: Have you a way to ping it via network or better ssh/vnc it from an other computer?

Comment: @Xvolks Nope. I‘ve also noticed that ~75% along the start up process, the progress bar disappear, the screen flickers, and then the progress bar reappears, the remaining progress bar fills way faster and then everything freezes.

Comment: Have you reset SMC and PRAM ?

Comment: @Xvolks I’ve edited the question, I think the core problem is the start up process. I have reset PRAM and will reset SMC in a minute.

Comment: @Xvolks After resetting SMC, the keyboard was responsive for like 5s, trackpad didn’t work from the beginning, and then everything went back to freeze

Comment: Can you boot a Linux live cd/usb? Else if you can find the ASD package on Internet you can boot on the EFI version to run a full diagnostic. You may also boot while pressing D key to enter built in diagnostics (not as useful as ASD, but it may help).